# Apollo GraphQL returns an empty field

Tags: postgresql, apollo, apollo-client, prisma-graphql

I want to query all the products no user has viewed.

The structure is

```
model Products {
  id    string
  views Views[]
}

model Views {
  id        string
  createdAt DateTime
  user      User
}

model User {
  id    string
  email string
}
```

I want to get all the products that no one has viewed. The following query is not working, but I think it should be similar (if this is possible)

```
query {
    Products(where: { views: { is: empty }}) {
      id
      views
    }
}
```

Comment: `views` is an invalid query. You need to query some fields on object types, like `views { id }`.

Comment: "*The following query is not working*" - what is the exact error message? What is the problem? What is the expected response, what is the actual result?

Comment: Thank you for the comments @Bergi. It may not be possible to write a query like this, but I want to list all the products with no views. The error message is `Field \"is\" is not defined by type`. I have been guessing other combinations like `every: {id: null}`, but it does not work either.